# How to work with onclick event getElementById

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

I'm designing an avatar module. The point is that when clicking on the hair or the eyes, they have to move at the top of the head. Instead of getting that, they do not move at all but the code also does not alert from an error.

[image]

Here's the HTMLcode:

```html
<style>

  #cabeza{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: auto;
    left:225px;
    top:125px;
  }

  #ojos {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 8px;
   top: 300px;
  }

  #pelo {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   left: 0;
   top: 125px;
  }

</style>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content">
   <div id="cabeza"><img src="assets/img/cabeza.png"/></div>
   <div id="pelo"><img src="assets/img/pelo.png" /></div>
   <div id="ojos"><img src="assets/img/ojos.png" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        alert('NOSeSiFunciona');
        document.getElementById("pelo").onclick = function() {document.getElementById("pelo").style.left = "225px";};
        document.getElementById("ojos").onclick = function() {document.getElementById("ojos").style.left = "235px"; document.getElementById("ojos").style.top = "200px";};

      </script>

 </body>
```

Comment: Your code works as expected. Look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOqYLN#anon-login. I removed the images and painted the divs so it would look nicer.

Comment: Thank you, and you're right, it works but not when i execute the code on my laptop. Thank you so much anyway.